# Prove that $\{f^{-1}(B_i)|i\in I\}$ is a partition of X.

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Could someone confirm what I have shown is sufficient in proving what was asked? I have no other way of checking my proofs and any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be surjective function and assume $\{B_i|i\in I\}$ is a partition of $Y$.
>
> Prove that $\{f^{-1}(B_i)|i\in I\}$ is a partition of X.

NTS: $$\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(B_i)=f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i)$$

Let $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(B_i)$

Then for all $i\in I$  there exists $y_i\in B$ s.t. $f^{-1}(y_i)=x$

Since $f$ is surjective there exists $j\in I$ s.t. $f^{-1}(y_j)=x$, so set $y=y_i$.

Then $y\in \bigcap_{i\in I}B_i$

So $x=f^{-1}(y)\in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i)$

Comment: I don't understand your proof - If $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I} f^{-1}(B_i)$ then $x\in f^{-1}(B_i)$ for all $i$, so $f(x)\in B_i$ for all $i$ which is contradition since $B_i$ partition $Y$. So no such $x$ can exist

Comment: Prove that $\{f^{-1}(B_i)|i\in I\}$ is what? A partition of $X$?

Comment: For each $i \in I$, we know $f^{-1}(B_i) \subseteq X$, so $\cup_{i \in I} f^{-1}(B_i) \subseteq X$. Let $x \in X$. Then there exists a unique $i \in I$ such that $f(x) \in B_i$, so $x \in f^{-1}(B_i)$ which proves the other inclusion. Let $x \in f^{-1}(B_i) \cap f^{-1}(B_j)$ for $i \neq j$. Then $f(x) \in B_i \cap B_j$ which is a contradiction since $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$.